# How to deal with too many $_POST variable conditions from ajax request at backend?

Tags: php, ajax, variables, optimization

At work, we write a PHP application. I'm only a junior, but I'm dissatisfied with the problem of processing AJAX calls.
Each of AJAX request is directed to the single appdata.php script. At appdata.php is 15k rows of this structure... $_POST['variable'] "variable" is every time different

```
if(isset($_POST['variable_1'])){
            // redirect to handling function       
            $returnArray['return'] = $model->DoSomeStuffWithVariable_1();
            // returnArray returns data after dosomething at backend
        }
if(isset($_POST['variable_2'])){
            // redirect to handling function       
            $returnArray['return'] = $model->DoSomeStuffWithVariable_2();
            // returnArray returns data after dosomething at backend
        }
if(isset($_POST['variable_3'])){
            // redirect to handling function       
            $returnArray['return'] = $model->DoSomeStuffWithVariable_3();
            // returnArray returns data after dosomething at backend
        }
if(isset($_POST['variable_xy'])){
            // redirect to handling function       
            $returnArray['return'] = $model->DoSomeStuffWithVariable_xy();
            // returnArray returns data after dosomething at backend
        }
```

I'd like to ask how it could be done better.
And how it is done on a professional scale, like as done on commercial websites where there are hundreds times more AJAX calls with hundreds variables...

Comment: Notice, the questions you ask have nothing to do with wordpress so they might be closed/moved to the proper stack form. If you have general php questions like this one ask them at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a good place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

I Would start with creating a array that hold all "conditions" logic, loop it, check to see if some condition is met and return the value.

```php
$conditions = [
    'variable_1'  => 'DoSomeStuffWithVariable_1',
    'variable_1'  => 'DoSomeStuffWithVariable_1',
    'variable_1'  => 'DoSomeStuffWithVariable_1',
    'variable_xy' => 'DoSomeStuffWithVariable_xy'
];

foreach ($conditions as $condition_key => $condition_value) {
    if (isset($_POST[$condition_key])) {
        $returnArray['return'] = $model->$condition_value();
        break;
    }
}
```

Now you might ask why in the `$conditions` I used only the method name instead of calling the method so that it will already contain the value.

The reason is to save resources, I don't know how many checks you have, maybe you habe hundreds, so instead of calling all hundred methods every time, we only call the method once only if the `isset` check passes.

The check also stops once we have found a valid condition so as to not use any more resources, because we only really need the one.